# Getting "embedded nul in string" in an RData file -- is the RData file format portable between windows and say OSX?

Tags: r

I was trying to load an old .RData file that may have been created on windows and I'm getting the following error

```
Loading objects:
  userLevel
Error in load("data.RData", verbose = TRUE) : 
  embedded nul in string: '03A93062\0\004\0\t\0\t\0\09C1DE6FFD3A3B75B'
```

Is this a known error?

I think I see the data in there it's just that there seem to be a lot of null characters -- which if I could get rid of would seem to work.

Comment: How did you transfer files between systems?

Comment: Good question -- I got it off a webserver