# Loading an rda file gives error: embedded nul in string

Tags: r, rda

I have an rda file which I am trying to load in R. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in load("filename.rda") : 
  embedded nul in string: '799654576857\0\0\0\020\0\0\0\001\0\004\0\t\0\0\0!Gram biomass per 100 sq'.
```

I understand the nature of the problem. There a string that R fails to parse, but I cannot figure out a solution.

Comment: Looks like happened many times, related post with no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36189478/680068 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/45489737/680068

Comment: Do you know how the rda file was created or where it came from? Did you create it yourself on the same machine?

Comment: The rda file was created by me on the same machine by making some API calls.

Comment: What kinds of API calls? Can you give any more details? Ir sounds like the file is just not formatted how R expects. If it was made with a program other than R, that could be a problem.

Comment: I used another way around to fix the problem. But now I am dealing with another error: error reading from connection. Should I create a new post for that?